# Ruby What is the most elegant way to do many next if

Tags: ruby

Im new to ruby, wrote this code and works but i know is not the most elegant way to do it, can you please help me to refactor it in the ruby way¡

```
  #Ckeck that is not a repetead user
  next if Profile.exists?(:screen_name => t.from_user) 
  next if SearchResults.exists?(:username => t.from_user)
  next if usernames.include? t.from_user
```

Comment: This type of questions belongs to http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: Oh Sorry, this is my first time on StackOverflow also. Please excuse me, im trying to do the things in the right way

Comment: No problem, just wanted to let you know :)

Comment: Why doesn't it get migrated to codereview instead of closed? It's a good thing people try to write elegant code. We should be supportive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your method is fine but personally, I would do something like this (with the info provided) ...

Use [`reject`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject) to limit your collection to the desired elements.

```
def repeat_user(user, usernames)
  Profile.exists?(:screen_name => user.from_user)    ||
  SearchResults.exists?(:username => user.from_user) ||
  usernames.include? user.from_user
end

User.all.reject{ |user| repeat_user user, usernames }.each do |user|
  # do your stuff here
end
```

Comment: oh very good solution, i like it a lot, thank you so much!